# Insignificant correlation between the variables that were tested to be highly significant in the other study

Tags: correlation

I have this burning question that variables are not significantly correlated to one another, where the other study I refer to keeps claiming that those variables (bullying victimization and perpetration) are highly correlated.
At first, I thought the researchers transformed the data by taking logarithm since they were highly skewed. So I did the same by taking the logs and transforming the data. When I put those transformed data into SPSS for correlation, only those victimization and perpetration variables are not correlated at all.
I also tried natural log and also square-root since log10 did not work. Kurtosis and skewness went down significantly by taking the logs, but how come they are not correlated as the previous study says?
It's weird because I'm using the exact same data from the previous study. Can anybody help? Any feedbacks are appreciated.
G8V1 is victimization type1. There are 4 victimization types, and 4 perpetration types so I separated them in my correlation. But when I summed and transformed the existing data, it still did not show any correlation like the other one I posted.

[image]
[image]

The authors mentioned in the article that "Before the SEM, any problems with the normality assumption of the three indicators of the latent variables, which were parceled for the stability of the model were examined (Little et al., 2002). The errors of the variables were not normally distributed. To deal with these problems, those parcels were inversely transformed (Kline, 2005). After the transformation, the non-normality problem was resolved. These transformed data were used for SEM with the FIML technique and raw data were used for SEM with MLR." Does it mean that they conducted Parcelling function in Mplus before conducting correlation?

Comment: The best way to answer would be to provide the paper and the data. Otherwise, it is not possible to answer. One can say that someone made a mistake as the most likely outcome, but who did what cannot be answered without all the information.

Comment: you're right. I just posted my correlation table and the other researcher's.

Comment: The best thing to do would be to e-mail the authors of the other study for exact details of the methodology they used to calculate the results.

Comment: Inversely transformed may mean taking the reciprocals. Try that.